# API to insert a new record to the leads (ODOO 12)

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

i'm working on odoo 12 , i have this Form that i build in my module 
[image]

### this the code file.py that contains the fields:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import api, models, fields
from odoo.exceptions import UserError
from odoo import exceptions
import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class ContactForm(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'form.contact.wizard'
    nom_v = fields.Char(string="Nom")
    prenom_v = fields.Char(string="Prénom")
    addresse = fields.Char(string="Adresse")
    tel = fields.Char(string="Téléphone")
    email_v = fields.Char(string="Email")
    ref_v = fields.Char(string="Référence du bien préféré")
    avis_v = fields.Text(string="Avis")

    @api.multi
    def contact_button(self):
        _logger.debug(' \n\n \t We can do some actions here\n\n\n')
```

### this the view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="my_contact_form_wizard">
        <field name="name">Formulaire de contact</field>
        <field name="model">form.contact.wizard</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <group>
                    <span>l'équipe de GestionIMMO vous remercier pour votre visite</span>
                </group>
    <group>
      <field name="nom_v"/>
        <field name="prenom_v"/>
        <field name="addresse"/>
        <field name="tel"/>
        <field name="email_v"/>
        <field name="ref_v"/>
        <field name="avis_v"/>
    </group>
                <footer>
        <button name="valider_form" string="Envoyer" type="Object" class="oe_highlight" />
                </footer>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

### i want an API that with clicking on the button 'Envoyer' transform those fields into a new record in the list of leads

### can anyone help me with that ? thanks

Comment: Are you considering converting this contact into a partner?

Comment: @Kenly , i don't understand ..

Comment: He asked , which is the model you want to create new record?. is it res.partner?

Comment: @Hello_world You need to call `create` method with your fields above using the corresponding `crm.lead` fields. If the contact is created as a partner then you just need to create a new lead for that partner.